# Why is python isinstance() transitive with base classes and intransitive with metaclasses?

Tags: python, metaclass

I am new to metaclasses, and may be using them in unintended ways. I'm puzzled by the fact that the `isinstance()` method appears to have transitive behavior when dealing with subclasses, but not when dealing with metaclasses.

In the first case:

```
class A(object):
   pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
     pass

ic = C()
```

implies that `isinstance(ic,X)` is true for `X` equal to `A`, `B` or `C`.

On the other hand, here is a metaclass example:

```
class DataElementBase(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = self.__initialisation_function__(value)

class MetaDataElement(type):
    def __new__(cls,name,initialisation_function, helptext ):
        result = type.__new__(cls,name,(DataElementBase,), dict(help=helptext) )
        result.__initialisation_function__  = staticmethod(initialisation_function)
        return result


###  test code  ####

# create a class from the metaclass
MyClass = MetaDataElement( 'myclass', float, "Value is obtained as float of user input" )

# create an instance of the class
my_instance = MyClass( '4.55' )

print ( 'MyClass is instance of MetaDataElement? %s' % isinstance( MyClass, MetaDataElement ) )
print ( 'MyClass is instance of DataElementBase? %s' % isinstance( MyClass, DataElementBase ) )
print ( 'my_instance is instance of MyClass? %s' % isinstance( my_instance, MyClass ) )
print ( 'my_instance is instance of MetaDataElement? %s' % isinstance( my_instance, MetaDataElement ) )
print ( 'my_instance is instance of DataElementBase? %s' % isinstance( my_instance, DataElementBase ) )
```

yields:

```
MyClass is instance of MetaDataElement? True
MyClass is instance of DataElementBase? False
my_instance is instance of MyClass? True
my_instance is instance of MetaDataElement? False
my_instance is instance of DataElementBase? True
```

That, is `MyClass` is an instance of the `MetaDataElement` metaclass, and `my_instance` is an instance of the `MyClass` class but not of `MetaDataElement`.

Is my interpretation correct? Is there a simple explanation for this?

Comment: Because subclasses are related types. Metaclasses are *types of types*. Not the same thing, and you shouldn't expect an instance to be an instance of the *metaclass*, it is an instance of the *class* and the class is an instance of the metaclass.

Comment: Yes your interpretation is correct. It's true definitionally; subclassing is not the same thing as a metaclass (hence why the name is different). Simply put `my_instance` has type `MyClass`, it does not have type `MetaDataElement`, so it is not an instance of `MetaDataElement`.

Comment: No surprises here. Not sure what useful answer anyone can give except "yes", since you've already answered your own question.

Comment: OK, the question is unclear. I've marked jsbueno's answer as correct because it adds some more context which helped me to understand a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion there is that `MyClass` is not an "instance" of `DataElementBase`. It is an instance of the metaclass: `MetaDataElement`, and an instance of all superclasses of that metaclass (that is: "type" and "object"). Just like what happens with instances of "ordinary" classes:

pasting your snippet in the interactive interpreter I can do:

```py
In [96]: isinstance(MyClass, MetaDataElement)
Out[96]: True

In [97]: isinstance(MyClass, type)
Out[97]: True

In [98]: isinstance(MyClass, object)
Out[98]: True

In [99]: MyClass.__mro__
Out[99]: (__main__.myclass, __main__.DataElementBase, object)
```

The relationship of "DataElementBase" towards "MyClass" is of "superclass". So, if you ask if it is a subclass of DataElementBase, you get True:

```
In [100]: issubclass(MyClass, DataElementBase)
Out[100]: True
```

The class bases are passed as the third argument on the call to `type.__new__`.

So, in other words: a "metaclass" is the "class used to build a class", and it has nothing to do with the inheritance chain of the created class. And conversely, a given object will always be an instance of any  "superclass" of its class. The metaclass is not a superclass of its class.

Once you understand that, you will notice that the behavior of "isinstance" and "issubclass" is the same across "non meta" classes and its instances, and "metaclasses" and the classes created through them.

---

On an unrelated notice, although your code work the way it is, it is not encouraged.: the signature for a metaclass `__new__` method should be conformant to the signature of `type.__new__` - and receive the metaclass itself, name, bases, namespace and optional keyword parameters.

The way you wrote it, departing your metaclass from this signature forces your code to declare classes the way you did: by explicitly instantiating the metaclass with a call. It can't be used as a metaclass that will create a new class from a a `class` statement and its body - as in this case, Python calls the metaclass with the parameters used by `type.__new__`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this answers my question and gives me a good learning point to work on. It also explains why methods which I add to `MetaDataElement` (not included in the snippet above) are inherited by `MyClass`, but not inherited by instances of `MyClass` (though this could be related to my use of a discouraged signature for `__new__`).

Comment: Indeed - methods on the metaclass are visible form the class itself, but not visible from its instances. That is because Python's search for attributes reach first on an instance class, then, if it is not a "data descriptor" there, Python sarches in the instance, then back on the class, and from there on the superclasses of the class. The attribute search never goes to the metaclass. It can be used on purpose to have classmethods that are not available from instances.

Answer (score 0):

The basic purpose of `isinstance` is to check whether an **interface** is available from an object.  The interface of (an object of type) `DataElementBase`, for example, might include that it has a `value` attribute.  Indeed, `my_instance.value` is 4.55.

The interface of (an object of type) `MetaDataElement` is that it is a **class** that, among other things, inherits from `DataElementBase`.  Is `my_instance` such a class?  No; it’s not even callable like classes are.  It is an *object* of such a class, but `isinstance(my_interface, MetaDataElement)` would imply that it *is* such a class.

Comment: This is incorrect. -1. `isinstance` check if an object is an instance of a given class (for which both its direct class, or any of its superclasses qualify). Period.

Comment: @jsbueno: Have I contradicted that statement?  The question is *why* `isinstance` has the behavior it does, not *what* that behavior is in an implementation sense.

Comment: isinstance does not check for interfaces.The language itself does not know about "interfaces" - except, maybe, by the recent static-typing Protocols. isinstance simply checks if an object is an instance (wow) of a class - that includes all superclasses of its direct class, including virtual superclasses. Attributes, methods and other things that define an  interface may or may not be inherited along that chain: isinstance don't and can't care about them.

Comment: even in this case, the OP's metaclass break what a "metaclass interface" would be, by using an incompatible signature for the `__new__` method.

Comment: @jsbueno: Of course there are no language-level interfaces, and you can skip calling base-class constructors.  That doesn’t change anything: I’m explaining the principle—in particular, the Liskov Substitution Principle—that motivates *having* a predicate for “Is this object’s type *X* or a class derived from *X*?” (but does not motivate considering metaclasses).  For a different question (“What does `isinstance` check?”), these details would be the answer—along with things like `__instancecheck__`.